# Obtener datos de un fichero .json

Tags: java, android, json, jsonobject

Estoy tratando de obtener datos de un archivo .json con volley en Android y siempre recibo el onErrorResponse. Quiero obtener el id del producto, la url es: https://es.openfoodfacts.org/cgi/search.pl?action=process&food_groups=en:milk-and-yogurt&tagtype_1=nutrition_grades&tag_contains_1=contains&tag_1=A&additives=without&json=1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest=null; 

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        try {
            JSONObject dataFiltrado = response.getJSONObject("products");
            JSONArray dataFiltrado2 = dataFiltrado.getJSONArray("0");
            JSONObject dataFiltrado3= dataFiltrado2.getJSONObject(0);
            
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error en lectura de datos..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

He probado obtener datos desde otra url y los obtengo sin problema.

Comment: ¿Qué contiene el `VolleyError error`? Prueba a hacer log de eso y ver lo que dice, puede ser de mucha ayda.

Comment: Log.i("erroor", String.valueOf(error));  I/erroor: com.android.volley.TimeoutError

Comment: Lo que no entiendo, es por qué, con otra url diferente y, haciendo referencia a otras etiquetas de otro .json todo va bien....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La URL que indicas tarda varios segundos en responder. Probablemente sería mejor buscar otra forma de hacer la petición más rápida.

Pero si quieres seguir usando esta URL, basta con darle más tiempo a Volley de "timeout" antes de que cancele la petición. La política de reintento de la petición es, por defecto, 2500ms (2.5 segundos) y se puede alterar definiendo una nueva política de `retry`.

Para ello, hay que añadir lo siguiente:

```java
jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(/* ...*/);
jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(
    new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, 1, 1F)
);
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

El primer parámetro del `new DefaultRetryPolicy` es el tiempo que puede pasar haciendo la petición, aquí indiqué `10000ms` o 10 segundos. El segundo es el máximo de reintentos y el tercero es el [backoffMultiplier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43224683/what-does-backoffmultiplier-mean-in-defaultretrypolicy), pero estos son los dos valores que usa por defecto, y no los he modificado.

Comment: Perfecto. He aumentado el tiempo a 15000ms y ya no entra en el error del onErrorResponse. Pero es cierto que, el tiempo de respuesta de esta consulta es demasiado alto y, voy a buscar otra manera de realizarla. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: @Chiscu si son datos estáticos o que se actualizan dinámicamente cada cierto tiempo, y no es necesario que estén totalmente "al día", podrías hacer un servidor intermedio que pida al servidor de origen (openfoodfacts) cada N minutos, almacene la respuesta y luego tu aplicación contacta a tu servidor. Incluso puedes hacerlo con funciones _serverless_ como las de Firebase.

Comment: Mira... pues me has dado una idea. Eso sí que lo puedo hacer. Todavía estaba dándole vueltas sobre cómo hacerlo. Gracias una vez más.